# Neovim Mason plugin cannot install Linters or Formatters

Tags: neovim, language-server-protocol, mason

I'm quite new to neovim and mostly use it for simple c++ development. Love the motions and customizability, however I cannot find what I'm doing wrong when trying to install the `clang-formatter` using [Mason](https://github.com/williamboman/mason.nvim) plugin.

Using the visual interface provided by Mason I navigate to the 'formatter' section, position my cursor on the `clang-formatter` option and press I. It starts something but always fails with the same error message: 
[Mason Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQBQ5.png)

*(I get the same error when installing linters)*

So far installing LSP's has been no problem, and I've tried to google what the 'Error: name cmd not found' meant but haven't found anything that seems related.

I've made sure to update both my `python3` and `python3-pip` packages. I believe that the `virtual environment` package became standard since python3.3 so I haven't installed that separately.

**':checkhealth mason' output**
[My Check Health](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k3t2.png)

If anybody has experienced something similar I'd love to hear how you've solved it!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using `sudo apt install python3.10-venv`, depending on your Python3 version.

Comment: This was the issue for me, though I had to install python3.11-venv

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using the command: `sudo apt install python3-venv` (I am using the Ubuntu 20.04 OS)

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed pynvim? It is what makes the bridge between neovim and python stuff I guess, it is optional to have it but could fix your issue. My healthcheck looks like this :

```
provider: health#provider#check
========================================================================
## Clipboard (optional)
  - OK: Clipboard tool found: xclip

## Python 3 provider (optional)
  - INFO: `g:python3_host_prog` is not set.  Searching for python3 in the environment.
  - INFO: Multiple python3 executables found.  Set `g:python3_host_prog` to avoid surprises.
  - INFO: Executable: /usr/bin/python3
  - INFO: Other python executable: /bin/python3
  - INFO: Python version: 3.8.10
  - INFO: pynvim version: 0.4.3
  - OK: Latest pynvim is installed.
```

To install pynvim (in your shell):

```bash
pip3 install pynvim
```